# Angular + Rails + MongoDB(mongoid) delete function won't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, mongodb, mongoid

I have an Angular app with a rails back end and using the mongoid gem as a database. I'm trying to make a delete function, but I can't get it to work.
I get

```
No route matches [DELETE] "/api/tags"
```

I can't seem to get the ID. I thought I was doing that in the factory. Otherwise, I don't know how to get it.

My code:

angular:

```
var myApp = angular.module('tagsapp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']);

myApp.factory("Tag", function($resource) {
  return $resource("/api/tags/:id", { _id: "@id"},
    {
      'create':  { method: 'POST' },
      'index':   { method: 'GET', isArray: true },
      'show':    { method: 'GET', isArray: false },
      'update':  { method: 'PUT' },
      'destroy': { method: 'DELETE' }
    }
  );
})

// Controllers
myApp.controller("TagListCtrl", ['$scope', '$resource', 'Tag', '$location',
                      function($scope, $resource, Tag, $location) {
  $scope.tags = Tag.query();

  $scope.saveNewTag = function() {
    Tag.create({ tag: $scope.newTag }, function(response){
      $scope.tags.push(response);
      $scope.newTag = null;
    });
  }

  $scope.deleteTag = function(tagId) {
    Tag.destroy({ _id: tagId }, function(response){
      var index = $scope.tags.indexOf(tagId);
      $scope.tags.splice(index, 1)
      $location.path('/')
    })
  };
}]);
```

and my rails controller:

```
class TagsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_tag, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  respond_to :json

  def index
    @tags = Tag.all
  end

  def show
    @tag = Tag.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @tag = Tag.new
  end

  def edit
    @tag = Tag.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    # @tag = Tag.new(tag_params)
    tag = Tag.create!(tag_params)
    render json: tag, status: 201
  end

  def update
    tag.update_attributes(tag_params)
    render json: tag, status: 201
  end

  def destroy
    @tag.destroy
    respond_with @tag
  end

  private
    def set_tag
      @tag = Tag.find(params[:id])
    end

    def tag_params
      params.require(:tag).permit(:name, :color, :order)
    end
end
```

and my view:

```
<div ng-controller="TagListCtrl" ng-style="{color: myColor}">
  <table>
    Name: <input ng-model="newTag.name"> <br>
    Color: <input ng-model="newTag.color"> <br>
    Order: <input ng-model="newTag.order"> <br>
    <button ng-click="saveNewTag()">Save</button>
  </div>
  <tr ng-show="tags.length" ng-repeat="tag in tags">
    <td>{{tag.name}}</td>
    <td>{{tag.color}}</td>
    <td>{{tag.order}}</td>
    <td>
      <a href="" ng-click="deleteTag(tag.id)">Remove</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>


</div>
```

rails routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope "api", defaults: {format: :json} do
    resources :tags
  end

  root to: "tags#index", anchor: false
end
```

I'm suspecting that my routes are off. So far, adding a new tag works in the rails `index.html.erb`. I didn't put in any templates for angular to route to.

Comment: How does your routing definition look like?

Comment: @miensol editted my post for you